# Reading Streaming Data using python

Tags: python, stream

I have a server ip:port from where continuous data is coming. I want to read this data using python and want to transfer in some file. I got this sample code over internet and changed it according to my need.

```
import socket
HOST = 'ip'   # use '' to expose to all networks
PORT = 10001

def incoming(host, port):
  """Open specified port and return file-like object"""
  sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  # set SOL_SOCKET.SO_REUSEADDR=1 to reuse the socket if
  # needed later without waiting for timeout (after it is
  # closed, for example)
  sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
  sock.bind((host, port))
  sock.listen(0)   # do not queue connections
  request, addr = sock.accept()
  return request.makefile('r', 0)
# /-- network ---


for line in incoming(HOST, PORT):
  print line,
```

After executing this, I am getting below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read.py", line 24, in <module>
    for line in incoming(HOST, PORT):
  File "read.py", line 17, in incoming
    sock.bind((host, port))
  File "<string>", line 1, in bind
socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

Note: When I access ip:port using web browser, i could see data getting printed on it in text format.

How should i proceed here?

Comment: Which protocol is on your server? Assuming the server is sending binary data without any particular known protocol just use the `socket` module, create a client socket, connect to the server and read data in a loop (see documentation)

Comment: What did you get with your research on the topic?  Why did this not solve your problem?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @mguijarr : server is sending data in text format.I have updated piece of code that i tried.It is working for localhost with nc but when i am giving actual ip , its not working.

Comment: @prune: please check updated question.

Comment: Much better; thanks!  The problem is that the given host:port combination does not represent a streaming service.  Try printing out exactly what you got for arguments, and then try the sock.bind directly from a Python command line; this will eliminate a few potential sources of error.

Comment: @Prune: i checked parameter that is being passed to bind, it seems to be ok. Just to confirm, I used netcat command (i.e nc ip port) and i could see streaming data on screen. Not sure what is going wrong here.